# Program is not outputting correctly to the output file

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to this site, and programming in not my strong suit, so I apologize if the way I word things are hard to follow. Below is a code I have written to calculate the odds of profiting from playing lottery scratchers. It is suppose to output the results to a .txt file. I am able to get it to output to that file, and the everything in the output file is correct, except for the name of the second game. It is missing a whole word. How my output file looks is shown below.

```
Game                     Cost      Odds      
-----------------------------------------------
SMALL BEANS              $ 1          1 in 1.67
 BOOTY, ARRR             $ 10   Not possible
 MONEY HU$TLA$           $ 20          1 in 99.80
```

The second and third games both have a space before they start, and I am not sure why. Also, the second game is suppose to say "Pirate's Booty, Arrr." I do not understand how a whole word is missing. Any help on how to fix this would be very much appreciated. My code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// Declaring Variables
int Profit;                         // The lowest dollar amount you want to profit
int CostOfTicket;                   // The cost of the ticket in the dollar amount
int NumberOfPrizes;                 // The number of possible prizes that can be won
int PrizeValue;                     // The value of the prize in dollars
int NumberOfTickets;                // The total number of tickets that were printed with that prize
int TicketsNotClaimed;              // The number of tickets with that prize that have not yet been claimed
double RemainingTickets;            // Total number of tickets that are remaining
double RemainingTicketsForProfit;   // The total number of tickets for a profit that are remaining
double Odds;                        // The odds of winning the game
string game;                        // The name of each game that can be played
string output;                      // The name of output file the user chooses (.txt)

// Open the input text file
ifstream inputfile ("scratcher.txt");  // Open the input file called "scratcher.txt"

// The program will ask the user to enter the lowest amount they would like to profit by when playing one of the lottery games.
// The games include "Small Beans," "Pirate's Booty, Arrr," and "Big Money Hu$tla$."
cout << "Enter the lowest dollar amount that you would like to profit: ";
cin >> Profit;

cout << "Enter the output file name: ";
cin >> output; //name of output file user chooses
ofstream outputfile (output.c_str()); //creates an output file with the name user chose for output
cout << "Generating report...";

// How the output will be formatted
outputfile << left << setw(25) << "Game" << setw(10) << "Cost" << setw (10) << "Odds" << endl;
outputfile << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl;

// Reads the name of the game
while (getline(inputfile, game))
{
    inputfile >> CostOfTicket; // Reads the cost of the ticket
    inputfile >> NumberOfPrizes; // Reads the number of prizes
    RemainingTickets = 0;
    RemainingTicketsForProfit = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPrizes; i++)
    {
        inputfile >> PrizeValue; // Reads the value of the prize
        inputfile >> NumberOfTickets; // Reads the total number of tickets
        inputfile >> TicketsNotClaimed; // Reads the number of tickets that are not claimed


        RemainingTicketsForProfit = RemainingTicketsForProfit + TicketsNotClaimed;

        // The next line will compute a sum of the number of the remaining tickets where the user would profit
        if (PrizeValue > Profit)
        {
            // The following line computes the running sum of the number of tickets remaining for that game.
            RemainingTickets = RemainingTickets + TicketsNotClaimed;
        }
    }

    // Tells the program what to do if there are no tickets remaining
    if (RemainingTickets == 0)
    {
        // Formats the output
        outputfile << left << setw(25) << game << setw (2) << "$" << CostOfTicket << right << setw(15) << "Not possible"  << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // Tells the program to calculate the odds.
        Odds = RemainingTicketsForProfit / RemainingTickets;
        outputfile << left << setw(25) << game << setw (2) << "$" << CostOfTicket << right << setw(15) << "1 in " << setprecision(2) << fixed << Odds << endl;
    }

    string blankLine;
    inputfile >> blankLine;
}

// Closes the input and output text file
inputfile.close();
outputfile.close();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why didn't you think the contents of the input file would be relevant to answering this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
string blankLine;
inputfile >> blankLine;
```

Not sure why you did this but it's eating up the first word of your next line.

Remember, `operator>>` into a `string` skips whitespace then eats precisely one word.

Whatever you're trying to do regarding skipping blank lines, this is not how to do it!

Comment: I did that because without it, it was only printing out the first line (small beans) and I could not figure out how to get it to print the next two games as well

Comment: I am not very proficient at all in programming. it is very tough for me and I am trying my best.

Comment: I'm sure you are. But you'll find it a lot easier if you do not attempt to get by through guesswork, but instead by studying, researching and thinking. Good luck.

Comment: I've been trying to do that, and still struggling. That is the reason why I was attempting to find help here.